# Customers admin page add grid column as order link in orders grid

Tags: magento2

I would like to add a column in order grid in the admin customer edit page, the column should be an order link that open the order details page in new tab.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customers admin page add grid column as order link in orders grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317108/customers-admin-page-add-grid-column-as-order-link-in-orders-grid)

Comment: Where's the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by creating a new module

in Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Column/Renderer/Link.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column\Renderer;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;


class Link extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
/**
 * @var Action\UrlBuilder
 */
protected $actionUrlBuilder;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context
 * @param Action\UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
   UrlInterface  $actionUrlBuilder,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->actionUrlBuilder = $actionUrlBuilder;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Render action
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
 * @return string
 */
public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
{
    $getData = $row->getData();
    $href = $this->actionUrlBuilder->getUrl(
        'sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $getData['entity_id']]
    );
    
    
    $orderID = $getData['increment_id'];
    return '<a href="' . $href . '" target="_blank">' . $orderID . '</a>';
}
}
```

In etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1"> <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/> </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Don't forget to replace **Module** and **Vendor** by your specific values and create a composer.json and registration.php files